# Не работает перегрузка оператора присваивания

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

```
class Overcoat
{
    int cost;
    char *name;
    public:

    void ShowCloth()
    {
        cout << cost << endl;
        cout << name << endl;
    }

    Overcoat()
    {
        name = new char[20];
    }
    Overcoat(int c, char* name)
    {
        this->name = new char[strlen(name + 1)];
        cost = c;
    }
    ~Overcoat()
    {
        delete[]name;
    }

    bool operator==(Overcoat &o)
    {
        if (cost == o.cost) return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool operator<(Overcoat &s)
    {
        if (cost < s.cost)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool operator>(Overcoat &s)
    {
        if (cost > s.cost)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    Overcoat operator=(Overcoat &s)
    {
        delete[]name;
        name = new char[strlen(s.name) + 1];
        strcpy(name, s.name);
        cost = s.cost;
        return Overcoat(cost, name);
    }
};
```

Когда в `main` создаю два объекта и присваиваю `obj1 = obj2` копирует только `int cost`. В name выводит мусор. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Где вызывающий код? И что это за `return Overcoat(cost, name);` в конце оператора присваивания. К чему это?

Comment: Все эти операторы должны принимать const ссылку. Кроме того, потенциально вы можете путать вызов копирующего конструктора (который кстати не определен совсем) и вызов оператора присваивания: `Overcoat obj1 = obj2;`.

Comment: Overcoat(cost, name);  это возврат безымянного объекта. У меня есть конструктор с двумя параметрами и я в него передаю изменённые поля

Answer (score 0):

Код содержит массу странностей, но основная ошибка заключается в том, что нарушено Правило Трех - в классе не определен правильный конструктор копирования.